# How to update a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I had a json which is inserted in my mongo collection.Now I want to update the same json that is inserted in the collection,in such a way that I need to add new data element to that collection using the id which will be generated earlier.
eg:

```
{
 "name":"sam",
 "age":20,
  "_id":""5sq8uye1236g'
 }
```

If above is the json what is inserted in one collection where we have `_id` generated for it in collection.
Now I had variable called token .

var token=12345

Now I want to update the above collection such that this token gets added to it based on the `_id` of that.
Required format in collection:

```
{
"name":"sam",
"age":20,
 "token":12345,
"_id":""5sq8uye1236g'
 }
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `update` command.

Your query should look like

```
db.collection.update({_id:'5sq8uye1236g'},{$set :{token :12345});
```

Read more about updating [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Comment: Thanks.But in my collection id is generating as "_id":{"_str":"5sq8uye1236g"}.Iam unable to update

Comment: `db.collection.update({_id:{'_str':'5sq8uye1236g'},{$set :{token :12345});
 `   Try this.

Comment: Any please refer the docs. These kind of example are plenty in there.

Answer (score 2):

### As of 2020/2021 use the ObjectId()

When updating by Mongo's ID **You cannot do it using simple strings**, you need to use ObjectId. For your example, say your ObjectId is `xxxxxxxxxxxxx`:

```
db.mycollection.update({_id:ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxx')},{$set :{token:12345}})
```

I can't say which is the minimum version but I have tested this since v4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.<collection_name>.update(
   { _id: 5sq8uye1236g },
   { $set:
      {
        "token": "12345"
      }
   }
)
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: Thanks.But in my collection id is generating as "_id":{"_str":"5sq8uye1236g"}.Iam unable to update

Answer (score -2):

```
db.<collection_name>.update({"_id":"5sq8uye1236g"},{
                        "name":"sam",
                        "age":20,
                        "token":12345,
                        "_id":""5sq8uye1236g'
                            },{ upsert:true})

db.<collection_name>.update({"_id":"5sq8uye1236g"},{ $set :{"token":12345}})
```